# Upload remote image in Firebase Storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

Is it possible to upload remote image to Firebase Storage using Angular 2?
We have a list of image `URL` which is hosted in some other server. Now we need to upload it to Firebase Storage

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. If the image is already stored somewhere else, why do you need to store it in Firebase Storage? More importantly, if you DO need to do that, why can't you download the image from your remote storage and then upload it to Firebase Storage?

Comment: we need to change the old serve and we have more than 5000 products and each product have minimum 12 images and it is not easy to reenter every product list in new server(firebase) so we need to merge it programaticly

Comment: we have json list which contain all product details and imge url . we need to stop our old serve and copy to firebase stroage and realtime database

Comment: I wasn't suggesting anything manual. My comment was to *download the image from your remote storage and then upload it to Firebase Storage* - you would do all of that programatically. What's preventing that from happening? It should be a brief amount of code - what have you tried?

Comment: if there is a function uploadfromurl() in firebase stroage my problem will solve , i am asking is there any method avalable like that?

Comment: There is no function like that in Firebase/Storage but the solution is to *download the data (images, etc) in your app*, then *upload it to Firebase storage*. It should be all of about 50 lines of code in total and take about 1/2 hour to craft the project. There's not way to provide more direction as that as we don't know anything about your 'other' server, how the data is stored or how it should be accessed. There are a lot of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714007/firebase-get-download-url-after-successful-image-upload-to-firebase-storage) available.