# In firebase Web Modular API how to get the image url from firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

In **firebase Web Modular API**. How to get the **image url** from firebase **storage** which is uploaded using the **uploadBytes**

here is the code

```
const app=initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);
export const storageRef=ref(storage)
export const imageStorageRef=ref(storage,"image")
```

```
uploadBytes(imageStorageRef, profileImage.name).then((snapshot) => {
   console.log(snapshot);             
 })
```

Comment: Have you followed the [documentation about getDownloadURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url)?  Are you having a specific problem with what you see there?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what is going wrong.

Comment: This is already answered in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70793497

Answer (score 2):

As Doug commented, this is covered in the documentation on [getting the download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url). In your case that could be:

```
uploadBytes(imageStorageRef, profileImage.name).then((snapshot) => {
  return getDownloadURL(imageStorageRef);
}).then((downloadURL) => {
  console.log(downloadURL);
})
```

Comment: That's not the modular SDK usage. getDownloadURL is a free function.

Comment: Good catch Doug. My mind still uses the namespaced API by default. Updated :)